# How to use a different Ruby for a different web application? Redmine error

Tags: redmine

I am trying to install a new version of redmine on my server.
Right now I have redmine 1.3.2 and I installed 2.4.3

But passenger can't open my application and I get this error :
[image: Redmine Error]

I have different rubies installed by accident. But I don't want to change it, since other applications are using ruby and I don't want to screw up anything.

Right now my RVM says that my ruby used is version 2.0.0 (using `RVM LIST`)

If I go for `which -a ruby` the output is this :

```
/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/home/me/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

so I tried to run a different ruby defined in my apache2. Using the official guide from passenger. But when I place in my apache this line :

```
PassengerRuby /path/to/my/ruby
```

I get an error "PassengerRuby not allowed to set here"

How can I use my ruby 2.0.0 for the new redmine? It now points to a 1.8 version as in screenshot provided

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (though not with redmine, and on CentOS 6). I wanted to switch to using ruby 2.3.0 on my production server for my app. Here are some steps I took:

Install ruby 2.3.0:

```
rvm install 2.3.0
```

Set it to the default. Note: run this as root/administrator.

```
rvm use --default 2.3.0
```

Installed the latest passenger:

```
gem install passenger
```

Installed the passenger apache2 module:

```
pasenger-install-apache2-module
```

The module installation script provides the code to put in your apache configuration, which for me looked like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
```

I put this in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf file, but it may be possible to put this in the apache configuration file for your particular app. The pasenger-install-apache2-module installation script will actually check your configuration files after you edit them and let you know if it finds any problems.

Then restart apache and as well as your app.